# Fluent NHibernate: How to Map M:N many-to-many with composite keys on both sides

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, many-to-many, composite-key

OK, so here is the problem. Its not even as crazy as the guy who wants to map m:n with different column counts in his PKs.

No matter what I do or where I look there seems to be no method chain that will result in a successful mapping of this.

I have tried doubling up on the Parent and Child columns, eg ParentColumn("").ParentColumn("").ChildColumn("").ChildColumn("") - didnt' think it would work and I was right.

Tried just using ForeignKeyConstraintNames no luck. Still FNH is mapping one side to a single key.

[image: problem domain]

```
        public partial class M2M2ParentAMap : ClassMap<M2M2ParentA>
        {
            public M2M2ParentAMap()
            {
                Table("`M2M2ParentA`");
                Schema("`dbo`");
                CompositeId().KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentAId1, "`M2M2ParentAId1`" ).KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentAId2, "`M2M2ParentAId2`" );
                HasManyToMany(x => x.M2M2ParentB).Schema("`dbo`")
                    .ForeignKeyConstraintNames("FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentA", "FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentB");
            }
        }



        public partial class M2M2ParentBMap : ClassMap<M2M2ParentB>
        {
            public M2M2ParentBMap()
            {
                Table("`M2M2ParentB`");
                Schema("`dbo`");
                CompositeId().KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentBId1, "`M2M2ParentBId1`" ).KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentBId2, "`M2M2ParentBId2`" );
                HasManyToMany(x => x.M2M2ParentA)
                    .Schema("`dbo`").ForeignKeyConstraintNames("FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentB", "FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentA");
            }
        }



        public partial class M2M2LinkMap : ClassMap<M2M2Link>
        {
            public M2M2LinkMap()
            {
                Table("`M2M2Link`");
                Schema("`dbo`");
                CompositeId()
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentA_Id1, "`M2M2ParentA_Id1`" )
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentA_Id2, "`M2M2ParentA_Id2`" )
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentB_Id1, "`M2M2ParentB_Id1`" )
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentB_Id2, "`M2M2ParentB_Id2`" );

                References(x => x.M2M2ParentA).Columns("`M2M2ParentA_Id1`","`M2M2ParentA_Id2`").Cascade.All();
                References(x => x.M2M2ParentB).Columns("`M2M2ParentB_Id1`","`M2M2ParentB_Id2`").Cascade.All();
            }
        }


ERROR:
Foreign key (FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentB:M2M2ParentAToM2M2ParentB [M2M2ParentB_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (M2M2ParentB [M2M2ParentBId1, M2M2ParentBId2])
```

AND

```
        public partial class M2M2ParentAMap : ClassMap<M2M2ParentA>
        {
            public M2M2ParentAMap()
            {
                Table("`M2M2ParentA`");
                Schema("`dbo`");
                CompositeId()
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentAId1, "`M2M2ParentAId1`" )
                        .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentAId2, "`M2M2ParentAId2`" );

         HasManyToMany(x => x.M2M2ParentB)
            .Schema("`dbo`")
            .Table("`M2M2Link`")
            .ParentKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentA_Id1`")
            .ParentKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentA_Id2`")
            .ChildKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentB_Id1`")
            .ChildKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentB_Id2`");
            }
        }


        public partial class M2M2ParentBMap : ClassMap<M2M2ParentB>
        {
            public M2M2ParentBMap()
            {
                Table("`M2M2ParentB`");
                Schema("`dbo`");
                CompositeId()
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentBId1, "`M2M2ParentBId1`" )
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentBId2, "`M2M2ParentBId2`" );

        HasManyToMany(x => x.M2M2ParentA)
            .Schema("`dbo`")
            .Table("`M2M2Link`")
            .ParentKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentB_Id1`")
            .ParentKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentB_Id2`")
            .ChildKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentA_Id1`")
            .ChildKeyColumn("`M2M2ParentA_Id2`");
            }
        }



        public partial class M2M2LinkMap : ClassMap<M2M2Link>
        {
            public M2M2LinkMap()
            {
                Table("`M2M2Link`");
                Schema("`dbo`");
                CompositeId()
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentA_Id1, "`M2M2ParentA_Id1`" )
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentA_Id2, "`M2M2ParentA_Id2`" )
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentB_Id1, "`M2M2ParentB_Id1`" )
                    .KeyProperty( x => x.M2M2ParentB_Id2, "`M2M2ParentB_Id2`" );

                References(x => x.M2M2ParentA)
                    .Columns("`M2M2ParentA_Id1`","`M2M2ParentA_Id2`").Cascade.All();

                References(x => x.M2M2ParentB)
                    .Columns("`M2M2ParentB_Id1`","`M2M2ParentB_Id2`").Cascade.All();
            }
        }

ERROR:
Foreign key (FKAB0E07EA57E45AB6:M2M2Link [M2M2ParentB_Id2])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (M2M2ParentB [M2M2ParentBId1, M2M2ParentBId2])
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[M2M2ParentA] ( [M2M2ParentAId1] [int] NOT NULL,
                                   [M2M2ParentAId2] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_M2M2ParentA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [M2M2ParentAId1] ASC, [M2M2ParentAId2] ASC ) )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[M2M2ParentB] ( [M2M2ParentBId1] [int] NOT NULL,
                                   [M2M2ParentBId2] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_M2M2ParentB] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [M2M2ParentBId1] ASC, [M2M2ParentBId2] ASC ) )


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[M2M2Link] ( [M2M2ParentA_Id1] [int] NOT NULL,
                                [M2M2ParentA_Id2] [int] NOT NULL,
                                [M2M2ParentB_Id1] [int] NOT NULL,
                                [M2M2ParentB_Id2] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_M2M2Link] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [M2M2ParentA_Id1] ASC, [M2M2ParentA_Id2] ASC, [M2M2ParentB_Id1] ASC, [M2M2ParentB_Id2] ASC ) )



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[M2M2Link]
        WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentA] FOREIGN KEY ( [M2M2ParentA_Id1], [M2M2ParentA_Id2] ) REFERENCES [dbo].[M2M2ParentA] ( [M2M2ParentAId1],
                                                                                                                               [M2M2ParentAId2] )
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[M2M2Link]
        CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentA]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[M2M2Link]
        WITH CHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentB] FOREIGN KEY ( [M2M2ParentB_Id1], [M2M2ParentB_Id2] ) REFERENCES [dbo].[M2M2ParentB] ( [M2M2ParentBId1],
                                                                                                                               [M2M2ParentBId2] )
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[M2M2Link]
        CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_M2M2Link_M2M2ParentB]
```

Update:
I have tried creating a custom key type but was not successful.

### Your challenge, if you choose to accept it:

Present code for the best **working** fluent mapping using this table structure, likely using a custom key type, and the bounty is yours.

Anyone?

Comment: I see an old patch submission in the google code repository that says it adds ParentKeyColumns and ChildKeyColumns, and what looks like the aborted implementation in the current github repo. hmmmmm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If FluentNHibernate is currently unable to map this, then you can map it with a hbm.xml file.

I also used a component for the composite id of both classes. This makes the identity separate from the entity, allowing `session.Get<M2M2ParentA>( new M2M2Id( 1, 2 ))`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301259/hibernate-composite-key/2301332#2301332) for a discussion of the 3 ways to represent composite-id (it is the same for NHibernate and Hibernate).

```
<class name="M2M2ParentA" table="M2M2ParentA">
    <composite-id name="Id" class="M2M2Id">
        <key-property name="Id1" />
        <key-property name="Id2" />
    </composite-id>
    <bag name="BList" table="M2M2Link" lazy="false" fetch="join" >
        <key>
            <column name="M2M2ParentAId1" />
            <column name="M2M2ParentAId2" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="M2M2ParentB" >
            <column name="M2M2ParentBId1" />
            <column name="M2M2ParentBId2" />
        </many-to-many>
    </bag>
</class>

<class name="M2M2ParentB" table="M2M2ParentB">
    <composite-id name="Id" class="M2M2Id">
        <key-property name="Id1" />
        <key-property name="Id2" />
    </composite-id>
    <bag name="AList" table="M2M2Link" lazy="false" fetch="join" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="M2M2ParentBId1" />
            <column name="M2M2ParentBId2" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many class="M2M2ParentA" >
            <column name="M2M2ParentAId1" />
            <column name="M2M2ParentAId2" />
        </many-to-many>
    </bag>
</class>
```

And my version of your classes.

```
public class M2M2ParentA
{
    public M2M2ParentA()
    {
        BList = new List<M2M2ParentB>();
    }
    public virtual M2M2Id Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<M2M2ParentB> BList { get; set; }
}

public class M2M2ParentB
{
    public M2M2ParentB()
    {
        AList = new List<M2M2ParentA>();
    }
    public virtual M2M2Id Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<M2M2ParentA> AList { get; set; }
}

public class M2M2Id
{
    public M2M2Id() {}
    public M2M2Id( int id1, int id2 )
    {
        Id1 = id1;
        Id2 = id2;
    }
    public virtual int Id1 { get; set; }
    public virtual int Id2 { get; set; }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id1.GetHashCode() + Id2.GetHashCode();
    }
    public override bool Equals( object obj )
    {
        M2M2Id other = obj as M2M2Id;
        return other != null && Id1 == other.Id1 && Id2 == other.Id2;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Lachlan, I will fire up that project and confirm tonight. thanks

Comment: @Lachlan, I have been covered up with other things but looking at your code I am confident I can work with it. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is that Fluent can't handle that situation yet, and you should map it with a .hbm.xml file.

The long answer is that Fluent CAN actually do it if the composite keys of your 2 parent tables are instead made up of foreign keys to 4 separate grandparent tables (GPA1,GPA2,GPB1,GPB2 - in the example below). In that case, the mapping could look something like this... (but it IS a bit hackey)

```
//OBJECTS
public class GPA1
{
    public virtual long ID {get;set;}
}
public class GPA2
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
}
public class GPB1
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
}
public class GPB2
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
}
public class M2M2ParentA
{
    public virtual GPA1 ID1A { get; set; }
    public virtual GPA2 ID2A { get; set; }
}
public class M2M2ParentB
{
    public virtual GPB1 ID1B { get; set; }
    public virtual GPB2 ID2B { get; set; }
}
public class M2M2Link
{
    public virtual M2M2ParentA LinkA { get; set; }
    public virtual M2M2ParentB LinkB { get; set; }

    public virtual GPA1 ID1A
    {
        get { return LinkA.ID1A; }
        set { LinkA.ID1A = value; }
    }
    public virtual GPA2 ID2A
    {
        get { return LinkA.ID2A; }
        set { LinkA.ID2A = value; }
    }
    public virtual GPB1 ID1B
    {
        get { return LinkB.ID1B; }
        set { LinkB.ID1B = value; }
    }
    public virtual GPB2 ID2B
    {
        get { return LinkB.ID2B; }
        set { LinkB.ID2B = value; }
    }
}
//FLUENT MAPPINGS
public class GPA1Map : ClassMap<GPA1>
{
    public GPA1Map()
    {
        Table("GPA1");

        Id(x => x.ID, "id_column");
    }
}
public class GPA2Map : ClassMap<GPA2>
{
    public GPA2Map()
    {
        Table("GPA1");

        Id(x => x.ID, "id_column");
    }
}
public class GPB1Map : ClassMap<GPB1>
{
    public GPB1Map()
    {
        Table("GPA1");

        Id(x => x.ID, "id_column");
    }
}
public class GPB2Map : ClassMap<GPB2>
{
    public GPB2Map()
    {
        Table("GPA1");

        Id(x => x.ID, "id_column");
    }
}
public class M2M2ParentAMap : ClassMap<M2M2ParentA>
{
    public M2M2ParentAMap()
    {
        Table("M2M2ParentA");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID1A, "M2M2ParentAId1")
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID1A, "M2M2ParentAId2");
    }
}
public class M2M2ParentBMap : ClassMap<M2M2ParentB>
{
    public M2M2ParentBMap()
    {
        Table("M2M2ParentB");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID1B, "M2M2ParentBId1")
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID1B, "M2M2ParentBId2");
    }
}
public class M2M2LinkMap : ClassMap<M2M2Link>
{
    public M2M2LinkMap()
    {
        Table("M2M2Link");

        CompositeId()
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID1A, "M2M2ParentA_Id1")
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID1B, "M2M2ParentA_Id2")
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID2A, "M2M2ParentB_Id1")
            .KeyReference(x => x.ID2B, "M2M2ParentB_Id2");
    }
}
```

There should be HasMany<> relationships in each of those mapping classes, but I got lazy. If you go the route of including a .hbm.xml file, I'd recommend using the .ExportTo("c:\") function when you configure your ISessionFactory and you can just edit the hbm file that fluent puts out. It's a great starting point.

HTH,
-Danno

Comment: @Danno, it would help if the question involved mapping a contrived structure likely never to be seen in the real world instead of the very possible, though poorly designed, scenario posited in my question. ;-)

Comment: @Danno, I might have accepted this answer if you had done more that state the obvious and present a completely unrelated scenario.  Maybe by posting the hbm to which you allude?