# Multiple Join Conditions in Hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, join

I'm trying to do this:

```
select * from A, B where A.id1=B.id1 and A.id2=B.id2
```

Assume relationship between A and B is `1-to-many`.

I'm using Hibernate mapping XML:

```
    <set name="mapAnalysisResults" table="ANALYSIS_RESULTS" inverse="true" cascade="all">       
        <key column="MAP_ID"/>
        <key column="ANALYSIS_OPER"/>
        <one-to-many class="com.st.wma.datalayer.hibernate.model.AnalysisResults"/>         
    </set>
```

Having multiple `<key>` tags inside `<set>` generates runtime error.

Is it possible to have multiple join conditions in Hibernate?

Comment: You mean a composite key?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301259/hibernate-composite-key

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple join conditions.  I suggest replacing the comma in between A nad B with 'join':

```
...from A a join a.B b on ...
```

If this doesn't work please send the error that you are getting.