# hibernate: insert instance with external "id class"

Tags: java, hibernate, insert, save, identifier

I'm using Hibernate + HSQL on JBOSS server, I need to saveOrUpdate() an Object which has an ID represented by another class:

```
public class RideId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int beginPop;
    private int endPop;
    private String requestUser;

public RideId() {
}

public RideId(int beginPop, int endPop, String requestUser) {
    this.beginPop = beginPop;
    this.endPop = endPop;
    this.requestUser = requestUser;
}
...
```

so, "RideID" is the ID of the entity "Ride"

```
public class Ride implements java.io.Serializable {

private RideId id;
private User userByRequestUser;
private User userByAcceptUser;
private Pop pop;
private Boolean rideStatus;

public Ride() {
}

public Ride(RideId id, User userByRequestUser, Pop pop) {
    this.id = id;
    this.userByRequestUser = userByRequestUser;
    this.pop = pop;
}

public Ride(RideId id, User userByRequestUser, User userByAcceptUser,
        Pop pop, Boolean rideStatus) {
    this.id = id;
    this.userByRequestUser = userByRequestUser;
    this.userByAcceptUser = userByAcceptUser;
    this.pop = pop;
    this.rideStatus = rideStatus;
}
...
```

how can I saveOrUpdate() a new Object of type Ride?

Thanks everyone and sorry for my english!

Comment: By using saveOrUpdate method, Where is your error?

Comment: is this a duplicated question? I guess you are after something like composite ID. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301259/hibernate-composite-key

Comment: yes, is a composite ID, but the classes are right, caming from a reverse engeneering already made by hibernate, I can't save a new object of type Ride because I don't know how to instanciate his ID!

@Fenil Shah:
I'm able to use saveOrUpdate method, but on entities that have a unique id (id composed by only 1 coloumn), with a composite id I don't know, for example, on which object call saveOrUpdate

Comment: First of all you need to be sure there is one to one mapping between your Ride and RideId class in your configuration file. Now you just have to pass Ride class object to your saveOrUpdate method as you have RideId object in Ride class hibernate will fetch your composite key data from RideId object and save it.

Comment: @FenilShah `RideId` shouldn't be a mapped class.

Comment: @dcernahoschi Look at Ride class. He has RideId object in it, so RideId must be a mapping class.

Comment: @FenilShah No. Please check the hibernate reference: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-id. Scroll a little bit to the section "Composite identifier". The composite id is not an `@Entity`, nor a `<class>`

Comment: @dcernahoschi oh ya you are right, thanks for make me understand.

Comment: @dcernahoschi & FenilShah   thank you for answering, I don't use annotations because I'm using hbm mapping classes, I know that RideId isn't an entity but it's however represented by a Java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. You need to create first a new `RideId`, assign it to a new `Ride` and call `saveOrUpdate` with the `Ride`.

```
RideId id = new RideId(1, 2, "someuser");
Ride ride = new Ride(id, ...);
session.saveOrUpdate(ride);
```

Comment: this is the right answer, I resolved it just now and did exactly what you did.

Thank you however!